# Vertically align column in row in Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, vertical-alignment, flexbox

I have the following `ion-view` :

```
<ion-view view-title="Success" ng-controller="successController" class="success-view">
  <ion-content>

    <div class="row row-center">
      <div class="col">

        <h1>Success!</h1>

        <h3>Your login credentials will be SMSed to you shortly</h3>

        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ui-sref="login">
          Okay
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I'm trying to vertically align that `col` in there in the screen. Now I understand that the only way this is going to work is if my `row` takes up 100% of the height. Yet if I go ahead and add `style="height: 100%;"` to my `row` it doesn't work, the row's height still wraps to it's contents. Even if I add `!important` it still doesn't span the full height of the screen... Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like Ionic framework adds a dynamic class `scroll` wrapping the row. Add a `height: 100%` to the parent `scroll` as well.

```
.row, .scroll {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[**Ionic Demo**](http://play.ionic.io/app/48e0abbdfcf5)

Comment: Works perfeclty! Thanks. Maybe it's just me, but from a mobile perspective I would find it more intuitive if the content area spanned 100% by default.

Comment: Yes, I would have liked that too. But it varies from developers point of view and standard way ;)